# Bad PHP script for downloading

Tags: php

I have a easy script:

```
  $url=file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
  $name=$_GET['name'];
  file_put_contents('temp.'.$_GET['ext'],$url);
```

It is script for downloading file by http. But file is so big (~10 Mb), and script stops with message:

"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded"

On my local server I can edit php.ini and set 300 seconds, but I can't do it on server on Internet. How can I do my task without editing php.ini? Give me example of code please, thank you.

Comment: If your hosting provider doesn't allow you to change the setting, there is nothing you can do

Comment: You can try overrriding thi with a custom php.ini in your root, but that's likely not to work. Contact your hosting provider and explain the situation, or find another way to achieve your goals, or buy a VPS

Comment: Did you tried [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/set_time_limit) ?

Comment: BTW writing to an arbitrary filename like that is not very secure

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can download file in parts:

```
$parts = 4;
$file_size = 500000;
$size_per_part = $file_size/$parts;

for($i=1;$i<$parts;$i++){ 
$url{$i} = file_get_contents('file.text', NULL, NULL, 0, $size_per_part);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit your php.ini file try following code to increase your;

```
// check if your web server accepts ini_set, before attempt to change anything
if(!ini_get('safe_mode')) {
    set_time_limit(240);
    ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
    ini_set("max_execution_time", "240");
}
```

More information about **[PHP ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)**.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to get around the script timeout. You'll need to start the download in the background and use another script to check on its progress.

```
exec( 'wget -b -O temp.' . $_GET['ext'] . ' "' . $_GET['url'] . '" > /dev/null &' );
```

Will execute wget (assuming your hosting service has wget) in the background and you can check the `wget-log` file that gets generated to see when it's done.

Comment: Wowza, massive security hole! If he is on a hosted account I very much doubt he will be able to run shell commands. If he is own his own server with it enabled then `$_GET['ext']` needs to be sanitised!

Comment: I don't think he will be able to use exec(). Considering many hosting companies are not allowing it and he can't even change php.ini, he won't be able to use exec() but it is a good information +1